# dotnetnuke - Build Install Package

Tags: git, dotnetnuke

I download and install Latest Build on (2018-01-31) from:
http://www.dnnsoftware.com/platform/build/nightly-builds

And also install this version and problems I have was solved.

Now I am trying to "self build" packages from sources from Git but my package in nothing like downloaded from previus link.

I download (development) sources from: https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform

Then I run Build_Install_Package.bat from root folder. Is this the right way do get the same that is in Dnn Nightly Build or what is the right way to build sources?